# In Sails.js lifecycle callback, how can I programmatically determine the model name?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two models, one that extends from the other.

I want to define a lifecycle callback in `BaseObject` that all of the sub-models can inherit. But I don't know to get the name of the model being acted on inside the callback. Some of the sub-models will need this info. e.g.,

```
{
  beforeCreate: function (model, next) {
    // I want to know the model's identity in here
  }
}
```

`model` is just a straight key/value list of the model's attributes, but it does not contain any schema information, such as the model's name. `this` seems to just point to `global`. I have access to the global `sails` object, but I don't know how to determine what **this** model is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up building this feature. I don't think it was possible before.

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/611